# How can I take the infinite integral of following equation with respect to r?

Tags: differential-equations

[image]

I need to do infinite integral with respect to $r_1$ in order to calculate $P_1$. I tried it using Matlab, but did not get solution. Can anyone give any suggestions. I badly need it to solve.

Comment: this looks like non-linear ODE in $p(r)$ right? then why are you using partial derivatives? and better to post the exact mathematical description of what we are looking at as it is not clear. what is $x,y,z$ there? Is there supposed to be a fraction sign in there?  (how did you manage to use Matlab on this thing?)

Comment: x+y ((∂^2 p_1)/(∂r_1^2 ))/((∂p_1)/(∂r_1 ))^2 +w ((∂p_1)/(∂r_1 ))/((∂^2 p_1)/(∂r_1^2 ))-z ((∂p_1)/(∂r_1 ))^2/((∂^2 p_1)/(∂r_1^2 ))=0                       This equation is basically the outcome from a matrics. For simplicity I set x,y w and z Instead of the the constant as those terms are big.  And I need to find out the value of P_1 which is a function of r-1 i.e P(r_1). That why I wanna apply infinite integral.

Answer (score 1):

> That why I wanna apply infinite integral
>
> And I need to find out the value of P_1 which is a function of r-1 i.e
>   P(r_1).

You have differential equation (non-linear). So just use `DSolve`

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, w, p, r];
ode = x + y*D[p[r], {r, 2}]/D[p[r], r]^2 + 
    w D[p[r], r]/D[p[r], {r, 2}] - z D[p[r], r]^2/D[p[r], {r, 2}] ==  0;
```

$$
\frac{w p'(r)}{p''(r)}+\frac{y p''(r)}{p'(r)^2}-\frac{z p'(r)^2}{p''(r)}+x=0
$$

> For simplicity I set x,y w and z Instead of the the constant as those
>   terms are big

Ok, lets try some constants (btw, it is not a good idea to use $x,y,z,w$ to indicate constants, it would be better to use letter such as $a,b,c,d$ for example for this purpose).

```
 x = 1; y = 2; z = 3; w = 4;
```

$$
-\frac{3 p'(r)^2}{p''(r)}+\frac{4 p'(r)}{p''(r)}+\frac{2 p''(r)}{p'(r)^2}+1=0
$$

Now call `DSolve`

```
 DSolve[ode, p[r], r]
```

it gives 2 solutions. The first is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you have initial conditions, may be it will be simpler solution.